# How to check if the job is done correctly (Python mechanize )

Tags: python, mechanize, html-post

I have this code that is doing this:
1. check some checkboxes
2. delete what i've selected

```
resp = mechanize.Request('http://some_url/manager.php', data)
cj.add_cookie_header(resp)
res = mechanize.urlopen(resp)
time.sleep(2)
```

data looks like this:

```
data = {'checkbox[]': '1', 'checkbox[]': '3', 'checkbox[]': '6', 'id': '1', 'submit': 'Delete'}
```

How can I check if the job is done correctly and if not, to try again? A sample code with be wonderful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the job is. Could you not just do `res.read()` and if there is some indicator in the body that would suggest it worked how you intended you could check it is in there? If the pertinent info is in the response url or headers then use: `res.info()` for headers and `res.geturl()` for the url.

Is this what you mean?

```
resp = mechanize.Request('http://some_url/manager.php', data)
cj.add_cookie_header(resp)
res = mechanize.urlopen(resp)
while res.read() == None:
    time.sleep(2)
    res = mechanize.urlopen(resp)
```

Comment: I want to do it automatically. I want something like a while loop, but new at python and i dont know how to do it.

Comment: So what would count as the job being done correctly? Do you just want to make sure the website received your request?

Comment: yes. I want to be sure that this request was process, before a move to another account.

Comment: I've updated my answer, still not sure I know exactly what you mean by 'request was process'